# Help debugging HDMI problem

Tags: 18.04, dell, hdmi

I have a DELL XPS13 laptop running Ubuntu 18.04. I've been using Dell's USB-C to HDMI adaptor to output the screen to a projector. It worked fine until just recently, started having some connectivity issues. As vague as it might sound, I've had problems for a couple of days where I would just manage to get it working again after connecting and reconnecting a few times, restarting, and switching window manager (from gdm3 to lightdm and back to gdm3 again), now I just can't get it to work again. When plugging in the HDMI cable, the laptop's response varies from just blinking for a second to not doing anything at all. Sometimes the projector shows up in Displays, sometimes not. Sometimes it shows as a second screen with the right model and resolution detected, sometimes you can see there's a second screen detected without any further details being shown.

What steps should I use to find the root of the problem? Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Try a new high quality HDMI cable.

Comment: Tried three different HDMI cables. I only have one HDMI to USB-C adaptor though, so I haven't been able to try with another one -- it's the Dell adaptor sold for the XPS-13

Comment: You can try a lower refresh rate. EG if it's at 60 Hz now, 45 Hz might work.

Comment: Didn't help. And maybe you missed the fact that I mentioned it had been working ok until now... also at 60 Hz. I'd like to properly debug the HDMI output to see why the signal is not reaching my projector.

Comment: FWIW I've just had this problem occur on a Dell Inspiron 5491 running Ubuntu 20. Screen been working fine via HDMI for 6 months, all of a sudden today I plug in and it's not working. Same screen works fine in another port, switch cable doesn't help.